# Rotate array to right instead of left

Tags: c++, arrays, loops, sorting, rotation

I have some code that rotates a number array to the left but instead, I need it to rotate it to the right. There is other code online that rotates array to the right but that code lets you only rotate numbers in the middle of the array.

I have tried decrementing the loops differently & and changing where its initialized but doesn't seem to rotate the correct way.

Expected output: if array is this `{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7}`. Then it should look like: `{7, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6}`

Current output: `{2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 1}`

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

/*Function to left Rotate arr[] of size n by 1*/
void leftRotatebyOne(int arr[], int n);

/*Function to left rotate arr[] of size n by d*/
void leftRotate(int arr[], int d, int n)
{
  int i;
  for (i = 0; i < d; i++)
    leftRotatebyOne(arr, n);
}

void leftRotatebyOne(int arr[], int n)
{
  int i, temp;
  temp = arr[0];
  for (i = 0; i < n-1; i++)
     arr[i] = arr[i+1];
  arr[i] = temp;
}

/* utility function to print an array */
void printArray(int arr[], int size)
{
  int i;
  for(i = 0; i < size; i++)
    cout << arr[i] << " ";


}

/* Driver program to test above functions */
int main()
{
   int arr[] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7};
   printArray(arr, 7);   

   leftRotate(arr, 1, 7);
   cout << "___" << endl;

   printArray(arr, 7);
   getchar();
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: It's not clear from your question whether the code you present is your working rotate-left code (in which case, it's of little relevance), or a not-working rotate-right attempt that you haven't bothered to rename.  You might also explain exactly what's going wrong with your attempt: what output it produces from the input, what you expect, and what you don't understand about how to go from one to the other.

Comment: Are you ruling out just using [`std::rotate`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/rotate)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`leftRotateByOne` is the key function here. The others can stay the same. Have a look at what it is doing, preferably with a pen and paper to keep track of the operations:

1. Keeps a copy of the first element.
2. Moves all elements to the "left" (that is, to the element with index
   one less), being careful not to overwrite anything you need later.
3. Puts the first element in the last place.

So you need to do the opposite:

1. Keep a copy of the last element.
2. Moves all elements to the "right" (that is, to the element with index
   one more), being careful not to overwrite anything you need later.
3. Puts the last element in the first place.

For example:

```
void rightRotatebyOne(int arr[], int n)
{
  int i, last;
  last = arr[n-1];
  for (i = n-1; i > 0; i--)
     arr[i] = arr[i-1];
  arr[0] = last;
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much Heath and super. I almost had got it working but with you help I got it to fully work! I can't seem to figure out how to specify a different starting point. For example the original array is {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7}. Then it should look like. {1, 7, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6} What do I have to do so that it starts at 2? I have tried changing what i is equal to but doesnt seem to work.

Comment: Good catch @super. So you don't want to include the first element in your rotation? Just don't let the index reach 0. So use `i>1` and `arr[1]`.

Comment: ohh that makes sense @Heath. Thank you again! This is very helpful. I hope the votes don't keep negative because my issue has been solved.